# Xcode 7.0.1 (7A1001) debugger "Unable to read data"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

I am learning the Swift programming language using Xcode 7.0.1. Now I have an error in my application which I try to debug, but the debugger is useless to me, because it cannot show the values of variables.

See the picture below:

[image: "Unable to read data"]

I am 100% sure the button has a label.

I did not find the solution so far.

Comment: is the button connected to the action in Interface Builder?

Comment: @vadian It must be, otherwise how will be the function called. Even if fired by code, sender is required.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information that you can get from the LLDB.  You need to have this open and it provides window that you can issues commands to as you are debugging to inspect variables. e.g the command p is print.

From your example this would then be 
"p operation " and the variable "operation" will be printed.

I am grossly simplifying the LLDB btw

[LLDB Apple docmentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/Introduction.html)

[LLDB commands](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html)

Comment: I get this from LLDB: `(lldb) p operation
(String) $R0 = unable to read data`

Comment: try outputting sender.currentTitle!.  you are unwrapping an optional - currentTitle of a button is there something in the buttons title?

Comment: Same: `(lldb) p sender.currentTitle!
(String) $R0 = unable to read data`

Comment: if you have reloaded the project - then try delete the button on the view and add the button again